# Python Packages - ImportError

Tags: python, import, error-handling

I am having a particularly tough problem here.

I am currently working on a personal project, starting with a relatively simple wrapper for the Riot API and all was working well until I wanted to package it and organize the modules. Here is the link to the project: [Logistic Analysis for LoL](https://github.com/shparki/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL/tree/dev_1.0) (I feel this would be easier than trying to describe the structure of folders, what is in the files, etc.

What I am trying to do is create a test suite to ensure that everything works as intended before continuing. At first I had a folder 'tests' under the main directory but am now just using tests.py; but I couldn't import 'pylol' (will be the main package), nor 'lol_api_wrapper' (a subpackage, wrapping the Riot API). I have the **init**.py files in each directory, so I am unsure why Python will not recognize the packages.

At first I was thinking circular imports, but I do not see any?

Thanks all....

Error Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mattmurray/Documents/GitHub/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL/tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pylol
  File "/Users/mattmurray/Documents/GitHub/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL/pylol/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import riot_api_wrapper
  File "/Users/mattmurray/Documents/GitHub/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL/pylol/riot_api_wrapper/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils import Session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/python3', '-u', '/Users/mattmurray/Documents/GitHub/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL/tests.py']]
[dir: /Users/mattmurray/Documents/GitHub/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL]
[path: /anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Comment: Can you show the actual text of the error you receive? I wonder if the problem is in python being unable to find the module...did you make sure that python knows how to get to the specified module?

Comment: Dang it- my bad. Definitely forgot to put in the text, I'll edit it into the post

Comment: This isn't exactly related, but having two folders `PyLoL` and `pylol` are extremely bad. Case sensitivity is not guaranteed by all file systems and builds. Which means that your code might work on some systems but crash on others.

Comment: This is actually a new error, but along the same lines as all the errors I have had before this one... Eventually, I always get to the same point "Import Error: Cannot import 'riot_api_wrapper'"

Comment: The two folders are a git error, my actual local repository only has the one 'pylol'- this is something I am working on, but I assure you that only one is present.

Comment: I have resolved the git error and confirmed that the repository is congruent with my local repo.

Comment: As an aside, `__pycache__` shouldn't be in the repo. It'll be built client side on first execution.

Comment: You are doing an absolute import from `utils` when in fact its package relative.

Comment: That's true- I was not intending to clean the repo until the packages themselves were working as intended (adding .gitignore, removing unnecessary files, updating readme and wiki, etc.)

Comment: @tdelaney could you elaborate? They are in the same folder so I thought I was importing it correctly? - what of the imports from the other files in pylol, are they correct?

Answer (score 1):

`from utils import Session` is telling python to search the module path for `utils`, but its buried in a package and won't be found. How would python differentiate it from another `utils.py` in someone else's package?

You are using package-relative imports at the `pylol` level (`from . import riot_api_wrapper`). Continue doing that in the subpackages, for instance, `from .utils import Session`. The dot tells python to look in the current package directory, `riot_api_wrapper` for `utils`. Two dots would have python look at the parent `pylol` directory.

After pulling your code, I changed the first imports in `pylol.__init__.py` and `pylol.riot_api_wrapper.__init__.py` to relative imports. Here's the diff:

```
$ git diff origin/dev_1.0
diff --git a/pylol/__init__.py b/pylol/__init__.py
index 746a67d..d9d493f 100644
--- a/pylol/__init__.py
+++ b/pylol/__init__.py
@@ -1 +1 @@
-import riot_api_wrapper
\ No newline at end of file
+from . import riot_api_wrapper
diff --git a/pylol/riot_api_wrapper/__init__.py b/pylol/riot_api_wrapper/__init__.py
index f51bb86..f831152 100644
--- a/pylol/riot_api_wrapper/__init__.py
+++ b/pylol/riot_api_wrapper/__init__.py
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-from utils import Session
+from .utils import Session

 from champion import Champion
```

I then ran the test from the base directory and it got past those first two imports. It failed on the next import that I didn't fix. There are quite a few of those and I am easily distracted.

So, worked for me!

```
td@mintyfresh ~/tmp/pkg/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL $ python3 tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pylol
  File "/home/td/tmp/pkg/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL/pylol/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import riot_api_wrapper
  File "/home/td/tmp/pkg/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL/pylol/riot_api_wrapper/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .utils import Session
  File "/home/td/tmp/pkg/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL/pylol/riot_api_wrapper/utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    import constants as const
ImportError: No module named 'constants'
```

Comment: When I try this, I receive an InputError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mattmurray/Documents/GitHub/Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL/PyLoL/riot_api_wrapper/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .utils import Session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.utils'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: Your linked repo doesn't match the errors you show which makes it difficult to figure out the exact details. Also, there is no `tests.py`. How are you running that thing?

Comment: tests.py is outside of the package under the top-level folder 'Logistic-Analysis-for-LoL'- I am working in the Dev-1.0 branch, not the main branch too

Comment: I pulled and ran the code with a few updates and it worked for me. I only fixed the first couple of imports so it failed at `constants` but you can work it from there. See my update for details.